# IOS build size is larger than it should be

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build

I did some google search but haven't found a specific answer for this. Here you can see that a project with only 2 sprites in it is supposed to be 4.8MB:

[image]

The unity project itself: 114 MB

The Xcode build(from unity): 809 MB

The IPA file: 137 MB

The app on my iPhone (through Xcode): 38.2 MB

If I understand correctly the combined sizes of all the files in my project are 4.8, so I would like to know how a 4.8 project turned out to be 38.2 on my phone? And is there a way to make those sizes much less and more representative of the actual project size, especially the IPA file which is the one that gets uploaded to the Appstore.
Also, I'd like to know given the above data, what is the size of the file that gets uploaded to the Cloud build.

Comment: What is the size of the unity engine?

Comment: If you using Xcode then disable the "Enable Bitcode" to No

Comment: Try a totally empty unity project, I think it is already 10mb despite the fact you loaded an empty scene and no asset. Then things start piling up. The fact your have 5mb of assets in file explorer, does not mean it will match in the build. There will be compression (or failed compression), addition of libraries and so on. This is why many games nowadays are shipped with few assets. They get all downloaded on first run of the game or before starting a level.